# Show that $e^{1/|x|}x$ does not converge.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

How can I show that $$\lim_{x \to 0}e^{1/|x|}x$$ does not exist, using the epsilon-delta definition of the limit?

Edit: In this context, $e^x = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2} +\cdots$

Comment: This depends greatly on how $e$ has been defined for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, with the change of variables $y=\frac{1}{x}$, we have $$\lim_{x\to 0+}e^{1/|x|}x=\lim_{y\to \infty}e^y/y=\lim_{y\to \infty}(1+y+y^2/2+\cdots)/y\ge \lim_{y\to \infty}(1+y+y^2)/y\ge \lim_{y\to \infty}y=\infty$$

A similar limit arises as $x\to 0-$.